# previous-line function in term-char-mode

Tags: term

Since emacs 26.1 (changeset 8a1576cc03) I can't do `M-x previous-line` in `term-char-mode`. The cursor always returns to prompt line.
On the other side, if I use the mouse or `M-x scroll-down` the cursor stay at the target point.

I try to write a function whitch can go up line by line in `term-char-mode` but without success. 
If someone has an idea, thanks.

Comment: I think you can set `term-char-mode-point-at-process-mark` to `nil` to avoid this (see its docstring).

Comment: @npostavs Thanks a lot it works with `(custom-set-variables '(term-char-mode-point-at-process-mark nil))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `term-char-mode-point-at-process-mark` to `nil` to disable this behaviour, otherwise it's not possible to write a command to circumvent it because the point is moved back after the command is run.  This is mentioned in `etc/NEWS` of Emacs 26 (emphasis added):

> *** 'term-char-mode' now makes its buffer read-only.
>
> The buffer is made read-only to prevent changes from being made by
>   anything other than the process filter; and **movements of point away
>   from the process mark are counter-acted so that the cursor is in the
>   correct position after each command**.  This is needed to avoid states
>   which are inconsistent with the state of the terminal understood by
>   the inferior process.
>
> New user options 'term-char-mode-buffer-read-only' and
>   '**term-char-mode-point-at-process-mark**' control these behaviors, and
>   are non-nil by default.  Customize these options to nil if you want
>   the previous behavior.